# Ajuda com input com , e . php com myslq

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso que o campo ACA e AIA retornem os valores com . ou virgulas, o código salva no banco de dado corretamente porém só mostra o número inteiro sem vírgula. Também está arredondando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
<?php
                $count = 1;
                $marks_of_students = $this->db->get_where('mark' , array(
                    'class_id' => $class_id,
                        'section_id' => $section_id ,
                            'year' => $running_year,
                                'subject_id' => $subject_id,
                                    'exam_id' => $exam_id
                ))->result_array();
                foreach($marks_of_students as $row):
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $count++;?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $this->db->get_where('student', array('student_id'=>$row['student_id']))->row()->student_code;?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $this->db->get_where('student' , array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->name;?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php $status = $this->db->get_where('student', array('student_id' => $row['student_id']))->row()->status; ?>
                        <input <?php if($status != '1' || $statusExam == 0) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> type="text" class="form-control" name="marks_obtained_<?php echo $row['mark_id'];?>"
                            value="<?php echo $row['mark_obtained'];?>">
                    </td>
```

Comment: Não faz muito sentido isso a menos que sua coluna seja `integer` no banco de dados. Deveria ser `double`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para salvar valores com ponto no `DB` a coluna tem que ser do tipo `FLOAT` e ela só entende ponto. Virgula não. É possível que sua coluna atual esteja do tipo `INT`. se estiver troque para `FLOAT`.